# How would I use recursion to create an array of extra change($100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1) MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion

How would I correctly make a recursive call within every if-statement to get the change of money? Im specifically focusing on the "change" variable.Thanks

TEST CASE 1-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<>> [change,flag] = makeChangeRecursive(2,100)

change =

50

20

20

5

2

1

flag =

1

> My code is the following

```
function [change,flag] = makeChangeRecursive(cost,paid)

if extra > 0

flag = true;

elseif extra == 0

change = 0;

flag = true;

return

elseif cost > paid;

flag = false;

change = [];

warning('That''s not enough to buy that item.');

return
end 

 if extra >= 100
```

> > change = [change; makeChangeRecursive(cost,paid - change )];

```
    paid =paid-100;

  elseif extra >= 50

    change = [change; 50];
    paid =paid-50;

elseif
```

This continues for all dollar values.

Comment: Would be nice to see the input parameters in the function definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your first case:

```
if extra >= 100
   change = [change; makeChangeRecursive(cost,paid - change )];
   paid =paid-100;
elseif ...
```

The first time we call your function, the variable `change` doesn't have anything in it. In fact, it will never have anything in it at the beginning of the function call because you don't pass it in as a parameter or give it a value prior to this line. So putting `change` on the right-hand side of the assignment will give you an error.

But that's okay, because that's not what you want to do anyway. You want to build `change` up from the beginning.

In addition, `change` is a list of values. We want to pass the recursive calls a single value, `paid` **after** updating its value.

Let's build this up step by step:

```
if extra >= 100
```

If this is true, we want subtract `100` from the amount paid (what we pass in to the recursive call) and add `100` to our list of change. Let's do the first part:

```
   paid = paid - 100;
```

As I said, we want to update `paid` first because we're going to use this value in the recursive call, which happens next, along with adding our new change value to the list:

```
   change = [100; makeChangeRecursive(cost, paid)];
elseif ...
```

And so on for the remainder of the change values. I'm sure you can take care of the rest of them now by yourself.

---

I also noticed that you didn't assign a value to `extra`. This might have been just a cut-and-paste error, but you need to make sure that you have that at the beginning of your function.

Comment: What do you mean by assign extra to a value , would extra = cost-paid work?

Comment: Actually, it would be `extra = paid - cost` since it is the amount by which you overpaid, right?

Comment: Yes that does make sense, my test case is working however I have an extra change value of 0

Comment: Yes, I noticed that :) That's a slight error in your base case here: `elseif extra == 0 change = 0;` Should I give you more of a hint?

Comment: Extra shouldn't equal zero? should it be [ ]?

Comment: You *almost* got it. :D You don't want to change `extra` because `extra` is the amount difference. You want to change the value that gets displayed at the end, `change`.

Comment: That should do it. It means that if you pay the exact amount (paid == cost) then your output will be empty, but you would have to add a bit more logic to get around that.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the logic of my code to make it shorter.             bills = [100 50 20 10 5 2 1]                                                                             extra = paid - cost                                                                                         index = find(extra>=bills)

Comment: Well, you would have to find some way to determine what denomination to use out of all of the possible denominations instead of hardcoding `100` or `50`... but I need to leave so I'll have to let you figure that one out.